# Have Site Sponsored

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Instructables has sections sponsored by Ace Hardware. I imagine this would help draw people into the site. I suggest we look at this option once the site goes completely public to help draw people in. Thoughts?

Comment: I think this is an interesting idea. Maybe it belongs under [the discussion on site promotion](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/105/how-do-we-promote-our-site)?

Comment: How will this draw people into the site?

Comment: @Vebjorn: Ace could run ads promoting and vice versa. Companies do the same for This Old House magazine, though the show and magazine have been around for a while.